# jQuery .fadeOut then wait, then .fadeIn doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to fade out a div, then fade in another div, and that works for me, the problem is I'm not able to delay it, so first div doesn't push the other div down...

This is my HTML (everything is inline):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript popup</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".main").hide();
        });
        $("#continue-button").click(function(){
            $(".vge-eksponering").hide();
            $(".main").show();      
        });        
    </script>
    
    <body style="background-color:lightgrey;">
        <div class="vge-eksponering" style="text-align:center;">
            <h1>Tjek VGEs hjemmeside ud på:
            <br>
            <a href="http://www.vge.dk" target="_blank">www.vge.dk</a></h1>
            <button id="continue-button" style="font-size:2em;">Fortsæt til VGE News</button>
        </div>
        <script>
            $("#continue-button").click(function(){
                $(".vge-eksponering").fadeOut(1200);
                $(".main").fadeIn(1200);
            });  
        </script>
        <div class="main" style="background-color:lightblue;">
            <h1>JavaScript popup</h1>
            <p>Hopefully this will work soon...</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I used this, and it worked.

```
$(".vge-eksponering").fadeOut(1200);
$(".main").delay(1200).fadeIn(1200);
```

Comment: You want to fade out `.vge-eksponering` and, when it's done fading out, fade in `.main`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have (at least) two choices:

If there's only one `.vge-eksponering` element, then use the completion callback [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) gives you:

```
$(".vge-eksponering").fadeOut(1200, function() {
    $(".main").fadeIn(1200);
});
```

Or just use [`delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) with a value equivalent to the first fadeOut:

```
$(".vge-eksponering").fadeOut(1200);
$(".main").delay(1200).fadeIn(1200);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `setInterval`

```
setInterval(function() {
  $(".main").fadeIn(1200);
}, 1200);
```

a tutorial on `setInterval` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: Set interval will call this function repeatedly.

Comment: If you use `setTimeout` that'll work. But it is better to use what [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35208618/1479535) says. Since these features will work more in sync, if used properly.

Comment: yup i agree @RejithRKrishnan, i knew this, but got confused while answering. somehow thanks for the info.. :)